# How would an "Atari Asteroids" type toroidal universe work?

Tags: science-based

The universe in which Atari's Asteroids is played would be a toroid when embedded in three dimensional space. I am interested in a universe where space is actually curved into a toroid. My question is, Could a toroidal section of the universe exist isolated due to curvature of space by an object such as a black hole? In other words, could some condition exist such that a toroidal piece of space would exist within the universe, could the asteroids game type world theoretically exist?

Comment: Why do you say it would be toroidal when it could as easily be spherical. The only thing that is required is that the universe be finite and closed, the game has nothing to say about curvature.

Comment: @A.C.A.C.The game absolutely *does* have something to say about curvature. The Asteroids game field is a topological torus, with zero intrinsic curvature. You could make a game otherwise identical to Asteroids, but with spherical topology, but the classic game is indisputably a toroid.

Answer (score 0):

**This wouldn't occur naturally, this wouldn't last long**

Of course other universes aren't bound to the same laws we are.

**Here's a picture of a black holes effect on space:**

[image]

To make a toroidal space you would need one at the center and then many making up a equatorial perimeter. The logistical problem then becomes this:

You would have all the black holes pulling on each other and the center black hole constantly pulling everyone in. In summation, all the gravitational forces are directed inwards, so the system would always collapse.

But, if you made all the outer black holes equal in mass and equidistant from the center and each other. Then gave the outer ones each enough velocity to maintain some kind of orbit. Then, yes, this could exist for some momentary amount of time.

Then, yes, you could play 3d asteroids anywhere in the toroid. Space wouldn't wrap it would compress allowing you traverse great distance. Though, getting out of the gravity would be a trick.